# Hochschild cohomology and outer automorphisms

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, automorphism-groups, hochschild-cohomology

Given an algebra $A$, I believe that the "conjugation" action of $\mathrm{Aut}(A)$ on $\mathrm{HH}^*(A)$ factors through $\mathrm{Out}(A)$. I’m looking for a reference.

Comment: In the context of group cohomology, something along these lines is stated in Proposition 4.1.1 of the book _The Cohomology of Groups_ by Leonard Evens. You might be able to construct an argument covering whatever more general situation you're interested in by arguing in a similar manner.